# Blazor Error trying to download from FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to deserialize a (in this case a PDF) file from a `FileStreamResult` on from an API Controller in the Blazor WebAssembly front end.

On the controller side I return the file;

```
    public IActionResult GetDocumentImage(int documentId)
    {
        var response = _service.Get(documentId);

        HttpAssert.Success(response);
        HttpAssert.IsNotNull(response);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(response.Result.Data);

        if (stream == null)
            return NotFound();

        return File(stream, response.Result.MimeType); 
    }
```

I have the following code;

```
 internal async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> BuildResponseAsBinaryStream<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
 {
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                 await responseContent.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                 memoryStream.Position = 0;

                 T obj = default(T);

                 BinaryFormatter binarySerializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                 obj = (T)binarySerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);

                 return new ServiceResponse<T> { Result = obj, HasError = false, HttpErrorCode = -1, Error = null };
             }

       }
 }
```

However, an exception is thrown at `await responseContent.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);`, I can debug this through Chrome using the client side debugger and Visual Studio but the `ex.Message` is `unable to evaluate`.

Comment: Deserializing a PDF !!!! What a strange idea ! Do you use the `BinaryFormater` to serialize your data ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I use a `FileStreamResult` from the API to return the file from the server. The reason I'm not simply adding to the `src` on an embed is because the endpoint is JWT protected. Hence why I am using the HttpClient where I add the token to the header of the GET. I suppose I really just need the `byte[]`?

Comment: Nope, the `BinaryFormatter` deserialize object serialized with a `BinaryFormatter` not from a PDF.

Comment: @aguafrommars ok but even if I do were to return `memoryStream.ToArray()` it not getting that far. Its throwing an error on the line `await responseContect.CopyToAsync(memoryStream)` line?

Comment: `Stream stream = new MemoryStream(response.Result.Data);
; if (stream == null)
            return NotFound();` stream is never null